# Write from 2D Array values into String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Hello I dont know how to write specific values from an Array[][] into a String[] Array. For Example:

```
String[][] matrix = new String[offerArray.length][3];

for (int i = 0; i < offerArray.length; i++) {
    String[] tempArray = offerArray[i].split("; ");

    for (int j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++) {
        matrix[i][j] = tempArray[j];
    }
}

// Result
String [0][1] = Name;
String [0][2] = Price;
String [0][3] = imgURL;

String [1][1] = Name;
String [1][2] = Price;
String [1][3] = imgURL;

String [2][1] = Name;
String [2][2] = Price;
String [2][3] = imgURL;


//Now I want to write the values into seperat Strings[] but how?
String [] all_name;
String [] all_price;
String [] all_imgURL;
```

How I can do this? Please help me.

**Solution that i searched:**

```
 String [] all_name = new String[offerArray.length];
 String [] all_price = new String[offerArray.length];
 String [] all_imgURL = new String[angebotArr.length];

 for (int i = 0; i < offerArray.length; i++){
     all_name [i] = matrix[i][0];
     all_price [i] = matrix[i][1];
     all_imgURL [i] = matrix[i][2];        
  }
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: What´s the definition of `angebotArr`?

Comment: can you give me an example which data are in there? Because you `split()` the value.

Comment: I get A long String with name;price;imgURL,name;price;imgURL,name;price;imgURL
then i split it by "," in a String Array and then i split it by ";" in a 2D Array, because i want to create String Arrays like name, name, name price,price,price imgURL,imgURL,imgURL

Comment: Why are a vew objects stored in 1 array element? you sould change this.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: What sould be the result in your `String[]`?

Comment: after I sort the values how I need, I put them in objects and load them into a adapter for the universal image loader.

Comment: String [] 1 = name, name, name;

String [] 2 =price, price, price;

String [] 3 =imgURL, imgURL, imgURL;

Comment: I would do this: create a model called `angebot.class` and then i add the attributes name, price and imageUrl. and now create an array or list with this objects.

Answer (score 1):

### Data format

So if I got you correct your 2D data looks like:

```
// First item
data[0][0] -> Name   of 1. item
data[0][1] -> Price  of 1. item
data[0][2] -> ImgURL of 1. item

// Second item
data[1][0] -> Name   of 2. item
data[1][1] -> Price  of 2. item
data[1][2] -> ImgURL of 2. item
```

And you want to achieve a result like this:

```
// All name values
data[0] -> Name of 1. item
data[1] -> Name of 2. item
...
// All price values
data[x + 0] -> Price of 1. item
data[x + 1] -> Price of 2. item
...
// All imgURL values
data[x + y + 0] -> ImgURL of 1. item
data[x + y + 1] -> ImgURL of 2. item
```

---

### Conversion

You can transform that easily using a `Map` first to collect all data and then transforming that **key-wise** into the array. Here's how it could look like:

```
String[][] data = ...
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> typeToData = new HashMap<>();

// Collect all data
for (int item = 0; item < data.length; item++) {
    // Get data for that item
    String name = data[item][0];
    String price = data[item][1];
    String imgUrl = data[item][2];

    // Add name data
    String[] nameData = typeToData.getOrDefault("Name", new ArrayList<>())
    nameData.add(name);
    typeToData.put("Name", nameData);

    // Add price data
    String[] priceData = typeToData.getOrDefault("Price", new ArrayList<>())
    priceData.add(price);
    typeToData.put("Price", priceData);

    // Add ImgURL data
    String[] imgUrlData = typeToData.getOrDefault("ImgURL", new ArrayList<>())
    imgUrlData.add(imgUrl);
    typeToData.put("Name", imgUrlData);
}

// Transform the data into the final array format
String[] result = new String[data.length * data[0].length];

// Set name data
int item = 0
for (String name : typeToData.get("Name")) {
    result[item] = name;
    item++;
}

// Set price data
for (String price : typeToData.get("Price")) {
    result[item] = price;
    item++;
}

// Set imgUrl data
for (String imgUrl : typeToData.get("ImgURL")) {
    result[item] = imgUrl;
    item++;
}
```

The field `result` now has the desired structure.

---

### More generic

You can of course drop the *type labels* (name, price, imgUrl) to create a more compact and generic solution like this:

```
String[][] data = ...
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> typeToData = new ArrayList<>();

// Collect all data
for (int item = 0; item < data.length; item++) {
    // Traverse all data of that item
    for (int type = 0; type < data[item].length; type++) {
        ArrayList<String> dataOfType = typeToData.get(type);

        // Create list if absent
        if (dataOfType == null) {
            dataOfType = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        // Add value and set
        dataOfType.add(data[item][type];
        typeToData.set(type, dataOfType);
    }
}

// Transform the data into the final array format
String[] result = new String[data.length * data[0].length];

// Set data
int entry = 0;
// Iterate type-wise
for (int type = 0; type < typeOfData.size(); type++) {
    // Iterate all items
    ArrayList<String> dataOfType = typeOfData.get(type);
    for (int item = 0; item < dataOfType.size(); item++) {
        result[entry] = dataOfType.get(item);
        entry++;
    }
}
```

Or alternatively use `Stream#flatMap` for the last part to achieve a more compact version:

```
// Transform the data into the final array format
String[] result = typeToData.stream()  // Stream of ArrayList<String>
    .flatMap(ArrayList::stream)        // Stream of String
    .toArray(String[]::new);           // Convert to String[]
```

---

### Separate data arrays

If you want to have the data for all types separated, you can use the intermediate result `typeToData`. It contains exactly that.

If you use the version where `typeToData` is a `Map`:

```
int amoutOfItems = data.length;

String[] allNames = typeToData.get("Name")
    .toArray(new String[amoutOfItems));
String[] allPrices = typeToData.get("Price")
    .toArray(new String[amoutOfItems));
String[] allImgUrl = typeToData.get("ImgURL")
    .toArray(new String[amoutOfItems));
```

And for the version with `typeToData` being an `ArrayList`:

```
int amoutOfItems = data.length;

String[] allNames = typeToData.get(0)
    .toArray(new String[amoutOfItems));
String[] allPrices = typeToData.get(1)
    .toArray(new String[amoutOfItems));
String[] allImgUrl = typeToData.get(2)
    .toArray(new String[amoutOfItems));
```

Comment: thx for your answer!!!  The data format that you wrote is like my format, but i want extract the values from my String[][] Array. 
Its dynamic loaded values from a server.
I dont know how to write my full loaded String[][] Array that is sortet like String[0][1] = name; String[0][2] = price; String[0][3] = imgURL into seperate String[] allNames, String[] allPrices, String[] allimgURL Arrays.

Comment: Ah I see. I've edited the answer (the last paragraph). Let me know if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution that i searched:**

```
            String [] all_name = new String[offerArray.length];
            String [] all_price = new String[offerArray.length];
            String [] all_imgURL = new String[angebotArr.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < offerArray.length; i++)
                {
                    all_name [i] = matrix[i][0];
                    all_price [i] = matrix[i][1];
                    all_imgURL [i] = matrix[i][2];        
                }
```